# How to update with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm facing a difficulty with the go orm gorm:

I have a structure like this:

```
type Data struct {
  gorm.Model
  UserID   int `json:"user_id,omitempty"`
  AnswerID int `json:"answer_id,omitempty"`
  Entities []Entity `gorm:"many2many:data_entities;"`
}

type Entity struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
}
```

And now, either if I do:

```
db.Model(&data).Where(Data{AnswerID: data.AnswerID}).Assign(&data).FirstOrCreate(&data)
```

Or

```
db.Model(&data).Where(Data{AnswerID: d.AnswerID}).Update(&data)
```

My many-to-many fields aren't updated but created... Leading to duplications if already exists.

If I try to play with the `Related()` function, it simply stop updating the foreign field.

Is there a way to update or create properly every tables linked?

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

To update your data just pass a struct with only the fields you wanna update:

```
db.Model(&data).Updates(Data{UserID: 2, AnswerID: 2})
```

and to add new entities:

```
db.Model(&data).Association("Entities").Append([]*Entity{&Entity{Name: "mynewentity"}})
```

Comment: Hi @Battalgazi, I notice that this solution is from the gorm documentation itself.
I came here from the docs there because adding new entities as the above doesn't work.
Have you tried yourself?

Comment: Check your database, append will add new records every time, so its not actually updating the association, just writing a new record and leaving the old ones there.

Comment: you can use `Association().Replace()` and run the two queries in one transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handled it is using a custom join table and just inserting or deleting the rows manually.

```
type DataEntity struct {
    DataID    string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    EntityID  string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt
}
```

set up the join table

```
err := db.AutoMigrate(&Data{}, &Entity{}, &DataEntity{})
err = db.SetupJoinTable(&Data{}, "Entities", &DataEntity{})
```

Then for deleting entities:

```
db.Unscoped().Model(&Data).Association("Entities").Clear()
```

To add entities:

```
dataEntities := []DataEntity{DataEntity{DataID:dataid,EntityID:eid}}
dbConnection.Create(&dataEntites)
```

Slightly cumbersome but it's the only solution I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only I found is this one:

```
db.Table("entities").
    Where(
        "id in (?)",
        db.Table("data_entities").
            Select("entity_id").
            Where(
                "data_id = ?",
                data.ID,
            ).
            QueryExpr(),
    ).
    Where("entity_name = ?", *entityName).
    Update(&data.Entity)
```

But I found 2 problems here:

1) Impossible to do a deeper subrequest:

```
Select("entity_id").
    Where(
        "data_id = ?",
        data.ID,
    )...
```

Won't work if instead of `data.ID` I want to go deeper with an other sub-request.
2) in case of multiple many-2-many I assume I would need to duplicate the query.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve according to the documentation using the Association.Replace
http://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Replace-Associations

```
db.Debug().First(&data)

data.Name = "New Name"

db.Save(&data).Association("Entities").Replace([]Entity{{Name: "mynewentity"}})
```

Comment: If you check your Entities table you will probably notice it is still duplicating values, but just updates the join table to the new value.